# 'Really!' Is it still an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech

I understand that 'really' is an adverb when it is describing an adjective in a sentence but what if it was an exclamation as in 'Really! I had no idea that was the case.' What part of speech would it be then?

Comment: I think it is still an adverb. Spoken on its own I think it should be followed by a question mark. *Really?*. It is an exclamation of disbelief, short for something like: *Did that really happen?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to be an interjection, just like "Indeed!" or "You're kidding!" It can still be viewed is an adverb ("Is that really so!"), but that would be a stretch, since it can also stand in for "I can't believe some people still think that Hals and Rembrandt knew each other personally," which is a complete sentence full of various parts of speech.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it can be an interjection since the speaker seems surprised. Thanks.